# renaming JPA Entities from Tables

Tags: jpa, ejb

I am reprograming an application. 
 The current database has table names like “User” which is a reserved word in the new db so I changed the table name to “NewUser”. I also had to change a few column names. I would like to code it so it imports the new name but changes them immediately in the app back to the reserved word so I don’t have to spend a lot of time re-programming:

Example Code:

```
@Entity 
 // NewUser is the new table name but still User below. I would like to keep the user 
 //as the class name but go after NewUser in the db 
 public class User implements java.io.Serializable { 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -6091824661950209090L; 
 /** Primary key */ 
 @Id 
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 

 // uid is now newuid in the table but again I want to keep uid in the app 
 //but reference newuid from the db 
 protected int uid; 

 public int getUid() { 
 return this.uid; 
 } 

 public void setUid(int uid) { 
 this.uid = uid; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `@Table(name = "NewUser")` to your entity. It will remap the entity to new table name, but keep `User` as entity name which is what is used in queries. You will only have to rewrite native queries if you have them, since that is pure SQL. Also, for renaming column names use `@Column(name = "newuid")`.